# Angular Firebase get list from firestore

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i want to know how to get lists from cloud firestore.

I upload list like this :

```
export interface Data {
  name: string;
  address: string;
  address2: string;
  pscode: string;
  ccode: string;
  name2: string;
}

constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore){
    this.notesCollection = this.afs.collection(`imones`, (ref) => ref.orderBy('time', 'desc').limit(5));
}

  notesCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Data>;

//creating item in list (imones)

createItem(){
  this.notesCollection.add(this.busines);
}
```

**Now the question is how to get all list items from there ?**

That's my try :

```
constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore){
  this.items = this.notesCollection.valueChanges();
}
  items: Observable<Data[]>;
```

HTML :

```
 <p *ngFor="let item of items">{{item.name}}</p>
```

ERROR:

> ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]'
>   of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as
>   Arrays.

Again error :

[image]

[image]

Comment: you probably need the async pipe : `*ngFor="let item of items | async"` .... read more at https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/pipes/async-pipe/

Comment: It shows nothing

Comment: hard to debug without knowing your data etc... would start by subscribing to valueChanges in your code and setting a breakpoint / log to console: i.e. `this.items = this.notesCollection.valueChanges().subscribe (  //debug here )` to see if you are actually getting any data from your Observable

Comment: I really think that there is one normal way of getting list objects from firestore, not just trying to guess..

Comment: this.notesCollection.valueChanges().subscribe( data => console.log(data)); - gives undefined. I will give a picture of what my items look in firestore.

Comment: this is telling you that your aren't getting any data from your connection... maybe your firebaseConfig is incorrect...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can iterate over an observable in your template like this. I would do something like this:

```
constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore){
  this.notesCollection.valueChanges().subscribe(items => this.items = items);
}
  items: Data[];
```